# How to make a component not overlap its parent's edges?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a widget that looks like this:
[image: Desired widget]
I have this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: theme.cardColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: theme.shadowColor,
            blurRadius: 5,
            offset: Offset(0, 2),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: theme.accentColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: Text(
                  "Alarm Date: " + widget.alarmDate.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: theme.textTheme.bodyText1?.color,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Switch(
                value: _isToggled,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isToggled = value;
                  });
                },
                activeColor: theme.accentColor,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(child:SizedBox()),
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: double.infinity,
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
            color: theme.secondaryHeaderColor,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                Text(
                  widget.repeatDays.join(" "),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: theme.textTheme.bodyText1?.color,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: SizedBox())

              ]
            )
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the result:

[image: Current widget]

The problem is that the bottom container overlaps its parent's edges. How can I make it fit its parents edges? I tried giving the same edge to the last container, but due to the different sizes, the bottom edges still looks different from the top edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `clipBehavior` on top Container, default it is none.

```dart
  return Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,/// or hardEdge, based on you
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: theme.cardColor,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the outermost container in a ClipRRect to cut the corners of the whole container (that contains the bottom container too).

Refer to the documentation on how to use it.

[ClipRRect class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html#:%7E:text=ClipRRect%20class%20Null%20safety,Google%20Developers)